# ios applicationDidBecomeActive stuck on splash screen

Tags: ios, background

I'm experiencing a phenomena that after a long time the app was in the background (and probably was ejected from the memory) - after running `applicationDidBecomeActive` (I see logs from it on the device log) it stays on the splash screen and stays there until I kill the app and restart it

Happens on an iPhone4 with iOS 7.1.2 (don't know about other devices, or if it happens on iOS8 as well)

Is there something I need to do in `applicationDidBecomeActive` to get the entry screen going?

P.S.
There is a facebook `[FBAppEvents activateApp];` invoked - I don't know if it is relevant or not...

Answer (score 0):

well..it is really depend on the app ,the device and how you are using you device.
test it. try to create  a new view controller and present it.

if it is presented, i assume that all your view controller were release from memory .

Comment: isn't it supposed to just start the app from fresh when it happens?

Comment: supposed ..but up to a limit. after all resources are limited, and you talked about a very long time in the background...

Comment: so what do I need to do? manually create the entry controller in the StoryBoard? how can I differentiate between this state and "regular" going back from background?